# NSTask output special characters convert to UTF8

Tags: macos, cocoa, utf-8, nstask

I'm running lsof through NSTask, pipe output and read into NSData. Then I create NSString with this data:

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Problem I see, is how NSTask interprets special characters. For file with name: `!@#$%^±^&*()ľščťžýáíé.docx`
I get this result: `!@#$%^\xc2\xb1^&*()l\xcc\x8cs\xcc\x8cc\xcc\x8ct\xcc\x8cz\xcc\x8cy\xcc\x81a\xcc\x81i\xcc\x81e\xcc\x81.docx`
Seems like decomposed UTF8 with hex encoded values. Unfortunately I'm not able to find a way of converting this to proper UTF8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that setting environment variable LC_ALL to en_US.UTF-8 does the trick.

```
[task setEnvironment:@{@"LC_ALL" : @"en_US.UTF-8"}];
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me, NSTask still produces decomposed utf-8.

Comment: Thank you! This was driving me crazy. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift `NSTask` is replaced by `Process`:

```
let process: Process = Process()
process.environment = ["LC_ALL": "en_US.UTF-8"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It work for me.

```
    NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary * e = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment]];
    [e setObject:@"en_US.UTF-8" forKey:@"LC_ALL"];
    [e setObject:@"en_US.UTF-8" forKey:@"LANG"];
    [task setEnvironment:e];
```

Comment: Could you explain what your code is doing and why it solves the problem.